# User reputation BUG!

Tags: discussion

I was checking my users page to see where am I regarding to other profiles and suddenly I found this:

[image]

How come I took 555 which is greater than Rinzwind (550) and Avinash Raj(547) respectively but I look the 4th ??

Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: The answer to all SE oddities: Caching.

Comment: Seems odd that it would update the score without updating the order.

Comment: @Oli There a lot of asynchronous caching issues across SE (such as the "0 questions featured, but the featured tab is highlit because it actually *does* have featured questions!" bug we had recently).

Comment: That's actually a lot more understandable. In this case the scores and their order are only used in this one place.

Answer (score 1):

I can only say it does not seem to be as much of a problem now (17:40 GMT 15th February 2014):

[image: AskUbuntu Users page]

Comment: Perhaps we should just chalk it up to cosmic rays :P

Comment: @ThomasW. Nah... Natural background radiation might have a bigger effect

Comment: How about the random convergence of spatial and temporal currents causing mayhem?

Comment: Laylines? Aliens? Wearing a red shirt?

Comment: All of the above.  :P  Anyways, enough with my offtopicness :)